# replace string in text based on another match

Tags: regex, awk, sed

So I have this file

```
a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 0 y
a computer x 0 y
```

I want to replace the `0` value with `111` value for the rows that have `window` in them. So the output will look like:

```
a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 111 y
a computer x 0 y
```

Running `sed 's/window.*0/y/' a.txt` does not give me what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "s/ window \(.\) 0 / window \1 111 /"
```

Parenthesis (which need to be escaped) "group" a match. You can refer to groups by sequential number in your replacement string, preserving the matched value.

As it is unclear what your "a" / "x"/ "y" could stand in for (are they always "a"/"x"/"y", or always a single lowercase letter, or...), I can't really give you an "optimal" `sed` line. If this is to be release-quality code, you need to make sure there can be no "false positives" (i.e. if "window" can appear at some other place than the second column). You could use the grouping mechanics I showed above to match the whole line, *ensuring* that "window" is in the second column... which could get hairy if a column could conceivably contain spaces. As I said, not enough information.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/window/I{s/0/111/}' input_file
a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 111 y
a computer x 0 y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following GNU sed solution:

```bash
sed -i -E 's/^(\S+\s+window\s+\S+\s+)0(\s)/\1111\2/' a.txt
```

Here,

- `^` - start of string
- `(\S+\s+window\s+\S+\s+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more non-whitespaces, one or more whitespaces, `window` text, one or more whitespaces, one or more non-whitespaces and one or more whitespaces
- `0` - a `0` char
- `(\s)` - Group 2 (`\2`): a whitespace

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EwQfHQ):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 0 y
a computer x 0 y'

sed -E 's/^(\S+\s+window\s+\S+\s+)0(\s)/\1111\2/'  <<< "$s"
```

Or, you can use `awk`:

```bash
awk '$2 == "window" && $4 == "0"{$4=111}1' a.txt > a.txt.tmp && mv -f a.txt.tmp a.txt
```

It means, if Field 2 is `window` and Field 4 is `0`, replace the fourth field with `111`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/9HDYCJ):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 0 y
a computer x 0 y'

awk '$2 == "window" && $4 == "0"{$4=111}1'  <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 111 y
a computer x 0 y
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you specifically asked for `sed`. With your shown samples please try following `sed` code. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eYuvgU/1) for used regex in `sed` code.

```
sed -E '/window/s/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)[^[:space:]]+(.*)$/\1111\2/'  Input_file
```

***OR*** To make sure that string `window` is coming in 2nd field/column then try following.

`sed -E '/^[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+window[[:space:]]+/s/^([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+)[^[:space:]]+(.*)$/\1111\2/' Input_file`

Output will be as follows:

```
a chair x 0 y
a table x 0 y
a window x 111 y
a computer x 0 y
```